# How to solve the spacy latin language import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

i installed spacy_stanza and downloaded the latin model, but i get this error:

```
ImportError: [E048] Can't import language la or any matching language from spacy.lang: No module named 'spacy.lang.la'
```

here's the code i use:

```
import spacy
import stanza
import spacy_stanza

stanza.download("la")

nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline("la")
doc = nlp(textstr)
for token in doc:
   print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_)
```

why does it not work? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spaCy doesn't have built-in support for Latin, so you need to load the pipeline a bit differently. See the [spacy-stanza docs](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza#stanza-pipeline-options). Modifying the Coptic example there slightly:

```
nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline("xx", lang="la")
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank you very much polm23, you are always reliable!!